# Fastest way terminal B to Terminal C in Newark airport

Tags: transit, ewr

We are arriving on United from Europe (Barcelona) into Terminal B and then departing in Terminal C for a United domestic flight (San francisco) .

What are the recommended /required transfers/travel methods/security checks.

Please note:  the similarly sounding question

[Is 2h 45m enough for a layover in Newark Liberty International transferring from an international to a domestic flight (Terminal B → Terminal C)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30451/is-2h-45m-enough-for-a-layover-in-ewr-transferring-from-an-intl-to-a-domestic-f)

Does NOT answer the question. in the answers they point out that the OP does not need to do B to C.Well.. *we do ..*  So please do not mark this question as a duplicate of that one.

Also the following:

[What is the connecting time to consider for International to International Transfers in US Airports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/what-is-the-connecting-time-to-consider-for-international-to-international-trans)

That question is too general - lacking specifics for this terminal.

We are asking specifically for this airport: which method to go (walk, bus, monorail) and which security we need to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fly into the US from another country and have a connecting flight, regardless of the airport, you have to (1) pass through Immigration, (2) collect luggage, clear customs, and drop off luggage, and (3) go through security in the departure terminal.

The amount of time all of this takes varies greatly even at a single airport, so it is hard to generalise about how long the process takes. I like to leave a couple hours connection just for my peace of mind.

I have flown through Newark many times and I am quite certain the fastest way to get from terminal B to C (and only way I have ever done it) is to take the monorail. It is literally a couple of minutes' ride between terminals. Usually the wait for a train is less than 5 minutes though on occasion it has been so busy I have had to wait for the next one.

Take a look at the [Newark Liberty website](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-to-from.html), where you can find a map and more precise train timing details depending on the day and time of your flight.

You will go through security when you get to terminal C.