# Do I need to re-check my bags when flying into the US on a transit through Newark Airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, international-travel, ewr

Travveling with SAS 907 from Oslo, Norway to Newark Terminal B. Transfer to Terminal C and further with United 239 to Nashville. Do I have to pick up the luggage at terminal B and bring it to terminal C?

Comment: This is a fairly frequently asked question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton:  I would have thought so as well, but it doesn't appear to have been asked specifically about Newark.  (You & I know that the procedure is the same for all international -> domestic transfers at US airports, but a random traveler might not.)

Comment: Also, related question which discusses the transfer procedure:  [Is 2h 45m enough for a layover in Newark Liberty International transferring from an international to a domestic flight (Terminal B → Terminal C)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30451/is-2h-45m-enough-for-a-layover-in-newark-liberty-international-transferring-from)

Comment: Relevant detail: are both flights on the same ticket or are these different bookings ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to carry your bags between terminals at Newark Airport.

When you check your bag in Oslo it should be checked through all the way to BNA.

However, like every US international arrival, you must pick up and carry your bag through Customs.

Once you have cleared Customs there is a special baggage drop immediately past Customs where you will drop your bag again.