# Is there a website that tracks flight connections so that you are almost guaranteed to miss?

Tags: short-connections

In the EU, generous delayed flight compensation makes it potentially profitable to always go for the tightest possible connections. If your inbound flight is delayed, you receive 300+ euros in compensation and a free hotel stay.

Is there a website that tracks connections that could potentially benefit a traveller who isn't concerned about time?

Comment: Jonathan “Machiavel” Reez ;->

Comment: Why would you receive a free hotel stay?  Or are you rather asking for missed connections where you *must* receive a hotel stay?

Comment: And does the flight have to cost less than the compensation received?

Comment: Note that just because a connection is tight doesn't mean that it's missable. The airline may feel able to make such a tight connection precisely because it's the same plane, so a delay on the inbound flight automatically delays the outbound one.

Comment: @npl receiving a hotel stay (due to no connections being available until the next morning) would be a bonus. And the flight doesn't necessarily have to cost less than the total compensation, just cheap enough to make your time worth.

Comment: @JonathanReez I see, you're not asking about traveling *only* for the purpose of making money.  It would rather be an added bonus on top or a trip you would anyway make?

Comment: @npl say I want to visit Greece and I see that Lufthansa has a flight from Prague to Thessaloniki that's almost always late. I'd definitely try my luck there rather than going for a direct flight.

Comment: You might also consider looking at very late (3+hrs) direct arrivals, even without missed connections you're eligible for compensation.

Comment: @JonathanReez Well, to maximize your chances for a big delay you'd have to take a flight from Prague to (say) Frankfurt such that there would only be one last flight to Thessaloniki that day (ideally with *any* carrier). This way, if you miss the flight you're pretty much guaranteed to get a night at a hotel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of an aggregator site that makes this easy to search, but you can get various levels of historical data from FlightAware if you're willing to dig into individual flights (14 days of history for an unregistered free account, 3 months for a registered free account, and theoretically years worth for a paid account).

Here's a sample of what the data looks like for an unregistered account for the first leg of the hypothetical Prague-Thessaloniki flight on Lufthansa.  You'd have to manually look up and join this with the data for the Munich-Thessaloniki leg and probably also apply some judgment as to what constitutes an unmakeable connection.

[image: FlightAware screenshot]