# Connecting at Newark from International to Domestic on United Air for arrival

Tags: united-airlines, ewr

I am arriving from an international flight on United Air. The connection time is 1H 30 M at Newark. I've never done it this way, so I'd like to know if the connection time is enough.  I will arrive in Newark at 11:45 am (Monday)from Europe. My next flight to Chicago departs at 1:15 pm. I have two checked bags. I have global entry. Another option for me is to get the next flight to Chicago at 3:07, which means the connection time is 3H 22M and seems a little long. But if 1H30M is insufficient for connection at EWR, I can change it to the later one. Your input will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that on a single ticket?

Comment: That's likely to be cutting it a bit fine. It depends how bothered you are about your luggage arriving with you. If it's on a single ticket, you have a bit more protection in terms of missing the first flight, and you'll get there eventually, but as for the transit time, things like weather and whether it overlaps with vacation times will also have an effect.

Comment: @StuartF "luggage arriving with you" isn't at play here - unless you're suggesting they might want to skip collecting their luggage which is a really bad idea (at a minimum, it'll result in customs going through your bags - standard procedure for international bags that have been deliberately abandoned by a passenger)

Comment: I think just over 3 hours is not long for an international to domestic connection, I would suggest a longer one myself.

Comment: Nicolas, Stuart, Doc, and Willeke - thank you so much for all your comments. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you literally have 90 minutes from arrival to departure then I think that's tight - you need to be at the departure gate perhaps 20 minutes before departure. If this is on a single ticket then your airline think it feasible, possibly because they anticipate early arrival. See : [my question here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93109/connection-times-how-much-incentive-do-airlines-have-to-be-realistic)

With Global Entry you can get to the baggage hall quickly, however you must wait for your bags and then take them through customs to the drop-off, this
doesn't take as long as normal checkin but still adds time, and is vulnerable to delays.

One big potential time consumer then is that you need to clear security again back into your Domestic Terminal. At Newark I've experienced some quite lengthy queue for that. Further, you may also need to get the monorail between terminals.

Personally, even though I'm guessing it's possible to make such connections I try hard to avoid them.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is very helpful!

Comment: While in the specific case of OP which has Global Entry Hilmar’s answer is probably more accurate, this one is good for other users for which it’s possible but could be tight. It’s worth pointing out that it’s possible for flight on the same ticket but definitely not on separate tickets, and that on the same ticket, if delays make the connection impossible the airline has to rebook the passenger on the next available flight.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is all booked on ONE single ticket, otherwise this answer is useless

> The connection time is 1H 30 M at Newark.

With global entry (GE), that should not be a problem unless there is major delay or they lose one of your bags. Clearing immigration with GE takes only a minute or so. You will have to wait for your bags but that should not take more than half an hour.  You can recheck the bags right after customs and head to your departure gate and terminal (which may require taking the air train). At your terminal you need to clear security again but GE should also give your TSA PreCheck and this is usually quite quick as well.

> But if 1H30M is insufficient for connection at EWR, I can change it to the later one.

No need. If you miss the connection (due to no fault of your own) United will automatically book you on the next flight. You can keep your short connection and just use the long one if needed. The only risk here is that the next connection might be 100% sold out, but that's quite rare.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This is booked on one single ticket on United :)  My main airport is O'Hare and it takes only a minute to go through immigration too! I have a priority service with bags and typically I don't need to wait too long for bags, and hope it will work that way at Newark. I am just not familiar with Newark, and this is very helpful. Thanks!!